# How to configure correctly Firebase with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Recently, I am learning React by following closely some tutorials but I have reached a point where my web application is stuck because I have not set up correctly the integration between ReactJS and Firebase. This is what I have so far.

```
var React            =  require('react');
var ReactDOM         =  require('react-dom');
var ReactFire        =  require('reactfire');
var Firebase         =  require('firebase');
var FirebaseAPIKey   =  require('xxxx-xxxx');
var rootURL          =  'https://fiery-torch-xxxx.firebaseio.com/';

var App = React.createClass({

mixins : [ReactFire],

componentWillMount : function(){
this.bindAsObject(Firebase.initializeApp(rootURL +'items/'),'items',FirebaseAPIKey);
},

render: function() {    
return <h1>how are you doing? Are you okay?</h1>
  }
});

var element = React.createElement(App, {});
ReactDOM.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

As you can see, I am using the version of FireBase 3.2.1 with ReactJS 15.2.0 but every time I run this web app I end up with the error that says my API Key is invalid. Any example that anyone can provide me to set up correctly this integration would be enormously appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to initialize the SDK with an outdated `2.x` style. The correct way now is:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref = firebase.database().ref('items');
```

I'd suggest taking a look at the [web getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and going from there.

Comment: how do you avoid being loaded more than once?....I'm facing this issue 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736739/reactjs-app-authentication-firebasefirebaseui-uncaught-error-firebase-app-nam